# React snackbar is showing behind the poup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, frontend

I am using the react-notifications-component snack bar, but I am getting an issue that my snack bar is appearing behind the pop-up. Is there a way to apply zindex?

Using <ReactNotification style={{ zIndex: 10000 }}/> . but didnt worked

```
   store.addNotification({
        // title: "Error",
        message: 'Please select option first',
        type: 'danger', // 'default', 'success', 'info', 'warning','danger'
        container: 'top-right', // where to position the notifications
        dismiss: {
          duration: 1000000
        }
      })
```

[image]

Comment: yes, you can use css

Comment: How to implement inline CSS there?? @madalinivascu

Answer (score 0):

In the function that actually renders the `notification`, you could either create a `css` file, follow the convention of any library you're using, such as `MaterialUI`, or simply use `inline-styling`.

Anyhow, you need to give it `z-index` with styles. Hard to tell where you should place that `style`, since you've posted very little code.

The easiest, although, not the cleanest approach is using `inline-styling`. Just find the `Notification` component, and add:

```
<Notification style={{ zIndex: 1000 }}> // Or any number that is necessary to make the Snackbar end up on top.
    ...
</Notification>
```

Comment: there is no notification component. the above code is in the else block. that's it. How to implement inline CSS there??

Comment: I'm assuming that you have some sort of Snackbar or Notification component? Where is the code that actually renders the notification? Could you please update your question with the specific code that renders the notification? I'm referring to the actual JSX

Comment: ok... i did  <ReactNotification style={{ zIndex: 10000 }}/> ... but it didnt worked

Comment: If you could import a .css file into that component, set `<ReactNotification className="notification"/>
Then in css create a .notification {z-index: 999999999 !important}
This might work, it's hard to tell. I suggest you open your page in browser, and inspect the popup, to see what it's z-index is, and then make the snackbar have a higher z-index

Comment: Another option is to instead of setting `style={{ zIndex: 99999 }}` to rather set `className={{ zIndex: 999999 }}` directly, if the component you're using doesn't support style.

Comment: had tried the earlier one but didn't worked... this one also didnt worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233884/discussion-between-thewanderer-and-sodnarts).